# How to simplify the expression $\frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(t')}?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am solving a Cauchy problem: $x'+\frac{x}{t\ln t}=\frac{1}{\ln t'}, \ \ x(e)=e$ and I came to an expression $\frac{\ln t}{\ln t'},$ that I don't know how to simplify or express differently. Can someone help?

Comment: What is $t'?$ Is it just a different $t$ value? Or is it the time derivative of $t$ (which would be equal to $1$)?

Comment: @AdrianKeister It is a derivative, I would also think so, but then the answer to the problem would be $x(t) = \frac{t}{lnt}$, but the correct answer is given as 

$x(t) = \frac{t}{lnt'}.$

Comment: What is wrong with $\,\ln(t)/\ln(t')?\,$ We don't know anything about $\,t\,$ so it is as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong in the wording of your question because $x(t)=\frac{t}{\ln(t')}$ is not solution of the equation 
$$x'+\frac{x}{t\ln (t)}=\frac{1}{\ln (t')}$$
$x(t)=\frac{t}{\ln(t')}$ is solution of the equation 
$$x'+\frac{x}{t\ln (t)}=\frac{1}{\ln (t)}$$
Possibly there is a confusion between $\quad x'+\frac{x}{t\ln t}=\frac{1}{\ln t},\:...\quad$ and $\quad x'+\frac{x}{t\ln t}=\frac{1}{\ln t'}…\quad$ that is a confusion between virgule and apostrophe, due to unclear typography.

Also, forgetting the parentheses can lead to confusion.